# golang Fiber no getting user register ID

Tags: go, jwt, fibers, go-fiber

I am learning fiber framework and JWT Auth. The register Func and Login Func correctly saves the user Id in the database. The cookie and JWT are are retrieved correctly and displayed the cookie and persisted on the front end. When I attempt to get the login UserId in the Controller I'm not expecting them to be 0.

I leave the code hopping have some orientation.
// Midleware:
const SecretKey = "secret"

```
func IsAuthenticated(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

cookie := c.Cookies("jwt")
token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(cookie, &jwt.RegisteredClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) 
   (interface{}, error) {
    return []byte(SecretKey), nil
})

if err != nil || !token.Valid {

    c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized)

    return c.JSON(fiber.Map{

        "message": "unauthenticated",
    })
}

 return c.Next()
}

func GetUserId(c *fiber.Ctx) (uint, error) {

 cookie := c.Cookies("jwt")

 log.Println("Cookie .........: ", cookie)

 token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(cookie, &jwt.RegisteredClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) 

 (interface{}, error) {

    return []byte(SecretKey), nil

 })
log.Println("Token .........: ", token)

log.Println("Error .........: ", err)

if err != nil {

    return 0, err

}
// var user dto.User
// expireTime := time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour)
// payloads := jwt.RegisteredClaims{
//  Subject:   strconv.Itoa(int(user.Id)),
//  ExpiresAt: &jwt.NumericDate{Time: expireTime},
// }

payload := token.Claims.(*jwt.RegisteredClaims)

id, _ := strconv.Atoi(payload.Subject)

return uint(id), nil
}

func GenerateJWT(id uint) (string, error) {
 expireTime := time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour)
 var user dto.User
 token, err := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, 
 jwt.RegisteredClaims{
    Subject:   strconv.Itoa(int(user.Id)),
    ExpiresAt: &jwt.NumericDate{Time: expireTime},
 }).SignedString([]byte(SecretKey))
 if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
 }
 return token, err
 }
 //Controller:
 func User(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
  var user dto.User
  id, err := middlewares.GetUserId(c)
  log.Println(id)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  confmysql.DB.Where("id = ?", id).First(&user)
  return c.JSON(user)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i answered this question before

u can access that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689355/16806783)

if u have question comment here for me